# Does the series $\frac{1}{(\log{n})^4}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have used comparison test to show it diverges:

$$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{(\log{n})^4}$$

But is this even right?

Comment: Yes it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is right - for $n$ big enough. After all, it is equivalent to $(\ln n)^4<n$, and using $e^x\ge 1+x$ we have 
$$n=e^{\ln n}=(e^{\frac15\ln n})^5\ge (1+\frac15\ln n)^5>\frac1{5^5}(\ln n)^5 >(\ln n)^4$$
at least as soon as $\ln n>5^5$.

Comment: Using Lambert function, it even seems that $n>\log^4(n)$ holds for $\log(n)>-4 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\approx 8.61317$, corresponding to $n>5504$